# Unexpected token '*' error occurs when trying to use the "import" keyword on a module

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I was trying to make an OBS extension when I ran into a problem with importing the module in the first place. I'm working in ES6, and using the Kruiz Control approach of making OBS load a webpage that connects to a local Websocket, and currently all I'm asking it to do is display the scene it switched to.

I verified that I had obs-websocket-js installed and then searched online about the nuances of import, however the suggested changes- switching out the * for OBSWebSocket, trying to use import 'obs-websocket-js', adding/removing type="module" from the script tag, and using require instead of import- yielded similar results.

```js
import * as OBSWebSocket from 'obs-websocket-js'    // The problem line

const obs = new OBSWebSocket();
await obs.connect(IP_REMOVED, PASSWORD_REMOVED)
obs.on('CurrentProgramSceneChanged', scene => {
    console.log(scene)
})
```

If there's any alternative, or a fix to this, that would be greatly appreciated.

Edited to include the way the script is loaded.

Comment: `import * as name from "module-name";` is valid syntax, inside a module, inside most browsers released since about 2018 (and earlier) - the issue is something you haven't mentioned - oh, wait, this isn't a browser, this is an OBS extension ... perhaps OBS extensions aren't the same as browsers then (though, all documents suggest your code is syntactically correct for OBS extension) can you show how the script is being loaded currently

Comment: Would there be a problem if the HTML file script tag also had the entirety of the script (shown in the post)?
(The "OBS Extension" is really just a webpage that has control over OBS)

Comment: it *should* work if the script tag is `type="module"` of course - but surely you can research that aspect in the available documentation

Comment: I've updated the post to include how the script is loaded.

Comment: Did you Try:
`import OBSWebSocket from 'obs-websocket-js';`

Comment: Yes, that was one of the fixes listed in the post. "switching out the * for OBSWebSocket"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resorted to just using Node. This is the finalized code snippet.

```
    var { default: OBSWebSocket } = require('obs-websocket-js');

const obs = new OBSWebSocket();
obs.connect('ws://192.168.1.143:4455', "4gPDLLGJhuUoCvOH")
obs.on('CurrentProgramSceneChanged', scene => {
    console.log(scene.sceneName)
})
```

Answer (score -2):

Try put semicolon after the package name, like this:  `import * as OBSWebSocket from 'obs-websocket-js';`

Comment: It still gives me the exact same error when I do that.

Comment: Semicolons are optional most of the time and this couldn't help because the engine already has problems with the second token (`*`)(i.e. it doesn't even get to the end of the line)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).